# Как хостить два скрипта на одном домене?

Tags: nginx

Есть два скрипта. Один на домене `xxx.ru`, другой на `xxx.ru/hite`.  Мой конфиг корректно отображает `xxx.ru`, но `xxx.ru/hite` выдает с ошибкой.

```
var/www/html/vfm/hite/index.php" is not found
```

Конфиг

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name xxx.ru;
    root /var/www/html/vfm;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend_71;
        }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxx.ru/hite;

        root /var/www/html/hite;

        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend_71;
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В server_name указывается доменное имя. Без пути. соответственно блок описания для сервера должен быть один. А уже внутри блока можете описывать разные пути, например с помощью боков location. `xxx.ru/hite` - это не домен

Comment: @Mike можно чуток кода)

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name xxx.ru;
    root /var/www/html/vfm;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
           fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend_71;
    }

    location ^~ /hite {
        root /var/www/html;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend_71;
        }
    }
}
```